# retrieve roles or parameters from Domain and trusted domains

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

I want to retrieve the information about those installed roles and its parameters (if possible ) from Domain Server and trusted domains NOT current computer I'm running on with cmdlets, powershell.

As far as I know that the `get-windowsfeature` is able to get all the available and installed roles in the current computer where I'm in.

Is there any chance to obtain those information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have permissions to access the computers in question and PowerShell remoting is enabled, run the command:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName DomainServer
```

Where DomainServer is the name of the computer you want to pull role information from.